# Why this Loop Logic by using .request does not work properly?

Tags: html, pandas, loops, while-loop, request

Can somebody help me and explain what is the mistake about my logic?

**Goal:**
After I get a result (url can be found by input f.e ibm), I want to enter another `stock` symbol by `input`. I dont want to start the little programm always by executing it from the beginning.

I tried to do it wih try&except, while, for[if], continue, pass, break.

Either I get the result

1. multiple times
2. just get "no data"
3. an empty dataframe --> []

Whatever I get, I want to use another `input` after the first  while loop was executed.

```
stock = input("Please enter a ticker symbol: ")
url = f"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=EMA&symbol={stock}&interval=weekly&time_" \
      f"period=10&series_type=open&apikey=MyAPI"
request = requests.get(url)
data = request.json()
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
#pd.set_option('display.max_columns',37)

while request.raise_for_status() == 200:
  print(df.head(37))
  print(input("Please enter a ticker smybol: "))
  if request.raise_for_status() != 200:
     print("no data")
     print(input("Please enter a ticker smybol: "))
```

thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You had your loop on the wrong place. Here is a working example.
If you type enter without input, it ends, if you type a valid stock it prints the dataframe, if the stock is invalid, it prints "no data".

```
import requests
while True:
    # get user input, expects a ticker symbol (e.g. ibm)
    stock = input("Please enter a ticker symbol: ")
    print('checking stock:', stock)
    # if user pressed enter (empty string), then finish
    if not stock:
        break # this breaks out of the while loop
    # craft URL, request the webpage and create the dataframe from the JSON data
    url = f"https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=EMA&symbol={stock}&interval=weekly&time_" \
          f"period=10&series_type=open&apikey=MyAPI"
    request = requests.get(url)
    data = request.json()
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    # if there is data, df.size will be greater than 0
    if df.size: # this is equivalent to df.size > 0
        print(df)
    else:
        print('no data')
# we are out of the loop
print('end')
```

*NB. there is no need to add further validation at this point, but if required you can wrap the request in a try/except block.*

Comment: thanks for your work :) unfortunately it is not working...because if you enter fe ’ibm’ it has to be found as a result, but it doesnt...it results in ’Process finished with exit code 0’...i added import pandas as pd to your approach because df = pd.Dataframe(data). It seems to stop already before print('checking stock:', stock)

Comment: I tested the code in a jupyter notebook and it was working fine for me. I got the data for IBM, 'no data' for junk and it stopped after blank enter

Comment: it works, thanks :) but to be honest i dont get it...during while True: ..where does the code knows from respectively where to look for? before it tests on ’if not stock:’ there is no url?

Comment: 'if not stock' tests whether there user input was empty and breaks the loop when this is the case. Then it crafts the url, makes the request and the test for data happens at 'if df.size' which is 0 if the dataframe is empty.

Comment: ah right, because of the different indents, right? break is the only row which refers to ’if not’. URL refers again to while...would makes sense if thats the point :)

Comment: I commented the code to make it easier for you to see what happens. Let me know if this works for you. Indentation is critical in python, so make sure to copy/paste the code exactly as it is here ;)